# Can't generate .svf in Quartus Prime lite

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I have a very simple project which just contains one file, It has completely complied fine. To program the device I need a  file but in the programmer the option 'Create JAM,JBC,SVF or ISC File...' is greyed out so I cannot select it.

Is this due to the version of the software that I am using?

OS: Ubuntu 16
Quartus version: 16

Answer (score 0):

To generate optional programming files, e.g. Serial Vector Format (svf) file, you should open **Device and Pin Options** dialog box by clicking **Assignments > Device > Device and Pin Options**.

In this dialog box you can decide, which additional programming files should be created during compilation process.